# Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x6f0063 SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I have this issue on Android 5.1.1 (OPPO phone)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x6f0063
   at android.os.BaseBundle.readFromParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1346)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.readFromParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1334)
   at android.os.Bundle.readFromParcel(Bundle.java:1046)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onResume(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onResume(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source:6000)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:2353)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:2599)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:2670)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.saveAllState(FragmentController.java:134)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:571)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:509)
```

It is hard to re-produce, but it almost occured on OPPO phone Android 5.1.1. 
Maybe it related to this issue 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37011984

Any workarround to fix it? Thanks in advance.

This is a part of activity xml

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

onCreate activity

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: I also have the same problem ... do you found any fix ???

Comment: Haha. Nope, just try-catch onCreate

Comment: May I know if you have found a workaround?. Multiple crashes are occurring in our production build on phone likes - Xiaomi, Oppo and Vivo.

Comment: Work around is... to disable StrictMode.